# ReactJS: Dynamic props in mother component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So my child component has a function that renders textfields based on `state.count` and every time a user presses a button the `state.count` will go plus one. As result, more textfields will render. The textfields has *onChange* and *value* that take props. How can I make those props **unique** for each textfield. Here I am rendering my textfields:

```
       let objects = [];
       const teamVelden = () => {

        for(let i = 0; i < this.state.count; i++){
            objects.push(
                <div>
                       <div className="col s5">
                            <TextField
                            id="standard-dense"
                            label="Teamlid volledige naam"
                            className={classNames(classes.textField, classes.dense)}
                            margin="dense"
                            value={this.props.teamlidValue}
                            onChange={this.props.onTeamlidChange}
                            error={this.props.tlnaamError === true ? true:false}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col s6">
                            <TextField
                            id="standard-dense"
                            label="Teamlid email"
                            className={classNames(classes.textField, classes.dense)}
                            margin="dense"
                            value={this.props.teamlidEmailValue}
                            onChange={this.props.onTeamlidEmailhange}
                            error={this.props.tlemailError === true ? true:false}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
            )
        }
        return objects;
    };
```

In the mother component i'm currently giving the textfield values like this:

```
 case 1: 
          return <StapTwee
                    teamlidValue={this.state.tlnaam}
                    onTeamlidChange={this.onTeamlidChange}
                    teamlidEmailValue={this.state.tlemail}
                    onTeamlidEmailhange={this.onTeamlidEmailhange}
                    />;
```

These values need to get dynamic as well I assume.

Comment: How about using index? `id={i}`